# Convert Uniocode to UTF-8 before sending json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode, utf-8

My rails app gets certain data in database from another application. That data is stored as text and it may have some unicode chars in it. Now my rails app does have UTF-8 set as default in the config. But when that data is sent as json to backbone front-end then those unicode chars and not converted properly and the front-end displays ? or smart-quotes instead of displaying the proper char. How do I force the rails backend to do the encoding on the backend to convert unicode chars to UTF-8 in the json?

Answer (score 0):

.encode('UTF-8') on each field.
Which is not that good, or you can write your own json serializer, where you can encode to any  encoding you want
http://matthewrobertson.org/blog/2013/08/06/active-record-serializers-from-scratch/

or patch the system one
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html